# Given $m^2\bmod A$ and $m^2\bmod B$, how do you find $m^2 \bmod AB$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Given $m^2\bmod A$ and $m^2\bmod B$, how do you find $m^2 \bmod AB$?

I'm 99% sure this is an application of the Chinese remainder theorem, although my workings do not quite show how it can be done.

You may of course assume $A$ and $B$ are coprime and that $m < A$.

Comment: Thinking it may have an application of Euclid's algorithm also

Comment: Simply use the Chinese Remainder Theorem on $m^2$. (If you like, let $x = m^2$.)